# Multi region active-active using S3 bucket in each region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm trying to design an architecture for a "simple" problem but for the moment I did not found the solution.

**The problem:**

I have a `S3 bucket` (one in each region with bucket replication in order to have the same thing in each bucket) and I would like to have a `CloudFront` in front of it to cache objects.

**My need**: to have the lowest latency for each user in the world when displaying an object from S3 bucket.

I wanted to have a CloudFront distribution in front of each S3 bucket and a `Route53` to route based on the latency to the nearest CF. The problem is that we cannot have many distribution for the same cname.

Here bellow the architecture I have so far (***which is not good***).

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is that you can create one single CloudFront distribution and you can attach a Lambda@Edge to it and use it to rewrite the host header in the request. Inside the Lambda you can access all the headers and you can rewrite them at will, based on any logic you want. When you rewrite the host header, the request will be sent to another bucket in another region. 
We used this solution to build multi-region active-active delivery from replicated buckets from two regions.
The original idea is from here: https://medium.com/buildit/a-b-testing-on-aws-cloudfront-with-lambda-edge-a22dd82e9d12
This seems to be the same solution for a different problem: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-amazon-cloudfront-with-multi-region-amazon-s3-origins/

We presented our solution on the AWS Summit in Berlin this year, but haven't posted about it yet anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep one of your buckets, AWS CloudFront does all of them for you.

**How CloudFront Delivers Content to Your Users**

After you configure CloudFront to deliver your content, here's what happens when users request your objects:

**1**-A user accesses your website or application and requests one or more objects, such as an image file and an HTML file.

**2**-**DNS routes the request to the CloudFront edge location that can best serve the request—typically the nearest CloudFront edge location in terms of latency—and routes the request to that edge location.**

**3**-In the edge location, CloudFront checks its cache for the requested files. If the files are in the cache, CloudFront returns them to the user. If the files are not in the cache, it does the following:

- CloudFront compares the request with the specifications in your
  distribution and forwards the request for the files to the applicable
  origin server for the corresponding file type—for example, to your
  Amazon S3 bucket for image files and to your HTTP server for the HTML
  files.
- The origin servers send the files back to the CloudFront edge
  location.
- As soon as the first byte arrives from the origin, CloudFront
  begins to forward the files to the user. CloudFront also adds the
  files to the cache in the edge location for the next time someone
  requests those files.

  [image]

For more info read the following doc:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowCloudFrontWorks.html

To deliver content to end users with lower latency, Amazon CloudFront uses a global network of 138 Points of Presence (127 Edge Locations and 11 Regional Edge Caches) in 63 cities across 29 countries. Amazon CloudFront Edge locations are located in:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I  know all that, but what I want to achieve is that when CF must go to the origin, I wand to minimize the distance between the chosen edge location and the origin. This means I need to find the nearest origin to my edge location.

Comment: No need to optimize that much. The latency will only be involved in the initial fetch. Once an object is in a cache, it doesn't need to go back to the bucket. Also, the initial fetch can be sped-up by a regional cache (which is between edge caches and the origin). If your data has a high hit-rate on the cache, there is no need to optimize the back-end. Stick with one bucket and one CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Actually my use case needs the much optimization possible. For a normal use case I would not care but for my case it is very important.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the need in your question. What about your use case makes this important? Without that a user who doesn't understand how CloudFront works may think they need this when they really don't.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS solutions has launched new solution to address the S3 replication across the regions.

For example, you can create objects in Oregon, rename them in Singapore, and delete them in Dublin, and the changes are replicated to all other regions. This solution is designed for workloads that can tolerate lost events and variations in replication speed.

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/multi-region-asynchronous-object-replication-solution/

Comment: That doesn't address the CloudFront requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, so sharing this updated answer, which makes use of S3 Multi-Region Access Points

[Always-on access for your data in Amazon S3, using cross-Region replication and Multi-Region Access Points (MRAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws/articles/76250275/always-on-access-for-your-data-in-amazon-s3-using-cross-region-replication-and)

Comment: That's good but doesn't address the CloudFront requirement, as you can't connect CloudFront to MRAP directly. There is a solution here https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-with-s3-multi-region-access-points

Comment: It would be great if AWS published an official guide to using CloudFront with MRAP, or supported it directly @Seth-E

Answer (score -1):

The answer seems to be pretty elaborate as provided by @Reza Mousavi. The point of AWS CloudFront distribution is to cache objects on the Edge locations worldwide (see options while configuring-attached snapshot).
Best practice (at least what I do -no complaints so far) is to configure a single distribution for each application origin. The option while configuring gives you the regions to choose based on your customer origin.

[image]

Comment: The problem with your strategy is that CloudFront is not designed to proactively cache anything.  The first time an object is requested through a given edge, and any time an object is requested from an edge that does not have a cached copy, it must be fetched from the origin.  The inherent delay in this process -- even though it is acceptable for many applications -- is what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: This would not work because we cannot have a Route53 latency based with several cloud front distribution with the same cname.